# jQuery Form Submission Parameter Check

Tags: jquery, form-submit

Can I intercept/interrogate the form submission values using jQuery in the `$('#formid').submit(function() { });` call?  I can't check the value from the page as it's the particular submit button pressed that I need to check.  I've found this [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20200806075031/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/renso/archive/2009/09/09/intercept-a-form-submit-with-jquery-and-prevent-or-allow.aspx) and it works in FF, but not in IE8, so that doesn't help, unfortunately.  I also don't want to have to attach submit code to the buttons as I was hoping to make a generic bit of code I could plug into a whole set of forms.

Cheers

MH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest jQuery 1.4 supports 'live' for submit events now -- meaning you don't have to attach individual handlers to all your forms. A nice example that covers what you've asked is given by Paul Irish here:

http://jquery14.com/day-05/jquery-1-4-hawtness-1-with-paul-irish

Here's my own take:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  var pageForms = jQuery('form');

  pageForms.find('input[type="submit"]').live('click', function(event) {
    var submitButton = this;
    var parentForm = jQuery(jQuery(this).parents('form')[0]);
    parentForm.data('submit-button',submitButton);
  });

  pageForms.live('submit', function(event) {

    // Prevent form-submission. You can do this conditionally later, of course
    event.preventDefault();

    // The form that was submitted
    var theForm = jQuery(this);

    // Detect which submit button was pushed
    var submitButton = theForm.data('submit-button');
    console.log('submitButton = ',submitButton.value);

  });

});
```

HTML:

```
<form>
  <input type="submit" value="submit form 1" />
</form>

<form>
  <input type="submit" value="submit form 2" />
  <input type="submit" value="submit form 3" />
</form>
```

http://jsbin.com/equho3/6/edit

EDIT - Sorry, I posted an example here that matched the one in your link! I've now provided a cross-browser solution.

Comment: Thanks - I've had a good look through that but I can't see where it covers interrogating the submission parameters - what I am missing?

Comment: I updated my answer with a better example to show how you can retrieve the submit-button value of any submitted form.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that, but it seems to access the page form object rather than the submitted values - if I do
theForm('input[type="submit"]').each(function() { console.log('button = ',$(this).attr('id')); });
it lists all my submit buttons rather than just the one clicked.  Does this work on your test system and return the value of the submit button clicked?

Comment: Scratch that last comment -- I've updated my original post to get the submit-button value, regardless of which form it came from, or if there are more than one submit-buttons within the same form!

Comment: Looks like you can't intercept the form submission parameters, so this is the next best thing.  I also found $('input').keypress(function(e) { if ( e.which == 13) { return false; } } ); helped as it stops the enter key submitting in input boxes but doesn't disable it for textareas