# jQuery: prevent form submission if the field before submit button is empty

Tags: jquery, form-submit

I've just started learning jQuery and already love it, but my skills aren't enough yet to solve this probably simple problem for my work: I have 3 different forms with an input field immediately followed by submit button:

[image]

I would like to prevent form submission if the text input field or the textarea before the submit button is empty. I've stolen a snippet from the [jQuery Ninja book](http://www.sitepoint.com/books/jquery1/):

```
$(function() { 
        $(':submit').click(function(e) {
                $(':text').each(function() {
                        if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
                                $(this).css('border', '2px solid red');
                        }
                });
                e.preventDefault();
        });
});
```

But it has following problems:

1. It ignores the textarea in the last form, because `$(':text').each()` does not apply to it
2. It doesn't allow submitting any form - I guess I need to move `preventDefault()` under an "if"
3. I probably should better use `prev()` instead of `each()`
4. If the user changes her mind and clicks another form, the previous form should be cleared

Could someone help me please? Alex

**UPDATE:**

I've tried:

```
$(function() {
        $(':submit').click(function(e) {
                $(this).prev(function() {
                        if ($(this).val().length < 2) {
                                // would be good to clear border for
                                // each text and textarea here...
                                $(this).css('border', '2px solid red');
                                e.preventDefault();
                        }
                });
        });
});
```

but unfortunately get 2 warnings:

```
Warning: Unexpected token in attribute selector: '!'.
Warning: Unknown pseudo-class or pseudo-element 'submit'.
```

and the red border doesn't appear and the form is submitted when a button is clicked.

Also I've tried:

```
$(function() {
        $('form').submit(function(e) {
                $(':text, textarea').each(function() {
                        if ($(this).val().length < 2) {
                                $(this).css('border', '2px solid red');
                                e.preventDefault();
                        }
                });
        });
});
```

but the form is never submitted and all 3 text fields turn red instead of just one.

Comment: instead of ` $(':submit').click()` try doing the same thing in `$('form').submit();`

Comment: Maybe this similar question will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119187/jquery-form-submission-parameter-check

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() { 
        $(':submit').click(function(e) {
                $(':text, textarea').each(function() {
                        if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
                                $(this).css('border', '2px solid red');
                                e.preventDefault();
                        }
                });
        });
});
</script>
```

You'll probably be ok with .each() :)

Comment: Thanks, but for some reason all 3 text fields have red border now and I need just one text field to be red - the one preceding the clicked submit button.

And have you missed a colon in ':text, textarea' or is it correct?

Comment: I would say make this specific to the form you are looking at rather than any submit (as the :submit selector does), but that is maybe me being old school and overcautious  - instead of $(:submit) replace with $("#{idofform}").click where {idofform} is the form id

Comment: I was hoping there is an elegant way without introducing 3 different #id_of_form's and 3 jQuery functions - since my 3 forms are all so similar: they have an input field (text or textarea) followed by a submit button.

Comment: no, textarea is correct but Shaun is probably right, you may want to target the elements more individually, at the moment, your selectors are very general

Comment: if ($(this).val() == ' ') {
Just a quick comment but you can also do this!

Answer (score 3):

Code for click and enter the submit button

```
 $(":input").bind("click keypress", function (evt) {

     var keyCode = evt.which || evt.keyCode;
     var sender = evt.target;
     if (keyCode == 13 || sender.type == "submit") {
         evt.preventDefault();

         //add your validations here
     }
```

and submit the form.

Answer (score 1):

1. Because `(':text') is equivalent to $('[type=text]')` so it doesn't include textarea. Change to `$(':text, textarea')`.
2. Correct
3. No, `prev` doesn't loop over the collection, `each` does. (`prev` selects the previous sibling of the current element)
4. Have a look a http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/  , it is a great validation plugin.

Comment: Thanks, but for 3. - I'd like to make just one text or textarea field red and not all. So I think I have to somehow use prev() to access the field preceding the clicked submit button.

Comment: Yes instead of looping through them all just use prev